# iOS 11 default quotation mark changed to ‘ ’ and “ ”

Tags: keyboard, ios

Before iOS 11, the default quotation marks were the ASCII `'` and `"`, but now they are changed to `‘’` and `“”` (curly quotation marks). I have to long press the quotation mark key on the soft keyboard to type the normal ones and have no way to type them on a Smart Cover.

I’m a programmer and I have to use `'` and `"`, is there any way to change them back?

I suspect this problem is linked to my language and region settings, I’m in China and my iPad language is English by the way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's in Settings | General | Keyboard | Smart Punctuation.

Comment: These are the correct menu item labels for iOS on iPhone. The other answer might be correct for iPad (I don't have one handy) but this one was right for my device.

Comment: @Seyren the other answer is wrong for any ios device

Comment: This is the correct answer for iOS 11. The former answer refers to recent versions of macOS (10.9 onward).

Comment: I managed to remap the words to my iOS device settings item from jmh's answer so I accepted it. Now since here's a more precise answer I'll tick this one.

Answer (score 8):

Go to system prefaces, keyboard. In the keyboard window click on the text tab. In this window, on the right, is an option to use smart quotes. Uncheck the box.

Comment: Only upgraded to iOS 11 from 9 today and spent the whole day reverting all the stupid stuff they've done. Cheers for tip!

Comment: This answer is for macos and is not correct for ios